# PHP Loop through array for value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that is being populated by a mysql query. I need to pull out a value and cannot figure out how to do it, I can only get the keys and not the actual value. The array is show below and I want to extract the "SERVICE" value using a loop so i can echo each one out

Here is the array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'SERVICE 1',
    'cwa' => 'SERVICE 1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'SERVICE 2',
    'cwa' => 'SERVICE 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'SERVICE 3',
    'cwa' => 'SERVICE 3',
  )
)

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$anames = array();


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $anames[] = $row;
}

foreach($anames as $key => $value) {
    echo($key);
}
```

Comment: If you are fetching the key , you will get the key , $key is a $key of value and $value is value of key , `replace echo($key);`  with echo `$value;`

Comment: What do you mean by "SERVICE" value??

Answer (score 1):

If you have the array like you shown in question and name `$anames` then do this.

Using the associative index:

```
foreach($anames as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['cwa']; //SERVICE 1, SERVICE 2, SERVICE 3
}
```

OR, using the non-associative index:

```
foreach($anames as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0]; //SERVICE 1, SERVICE 2, SERVICE 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks, missed the obvious !  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo $value[0];` / `echo $value[cwa];`  instead of `echo($key);`

Comment: Thanks, missed the obvious !  :)